# Seafile iOS - no available certificates

Tags: ios, docker, certificate, cloud

Recently got logged out of seafile on my iOS device - when trying to log back in I receive the error “No Certificates Available”

My HTTPS/SSL seems to look good, valid cert and all that and it works fine from the web client. I tried disabling SSL but still no connection. Not really sure what changed or what’s going wrong here.

I use Cloudflare for my DNS however the problem doesn’t seem to lie here either as far as I can tell.

Worth noting maybe too this is on a subdomain of a domain I use for other sites as well - i.e., cloud.domain.com

Any advice would be really helpful, I really relied on the camera upload feature and will be pretty upset without it which can’t be emulated through the web UI

If it’s meaningful as well this is a self hosted instance via Docker.